# Best practise for JPA merge and create

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using Java EE 7 with JPA (Eclipselink).

I have a simple database:

A membership, a person and a persongroup. A Persongroup has memberships. A Membership has a person and a persongroup.

My code to add a membership to a persongroup:

```
Membership membership = new Membership();
membership.setPerson(person);
membership.setPersonGroup(personGroup);
personGroup.getMemberships().add(membership);

membershipSession.persist(membership);
```

This snippet works. It is creating the Membership with the person and the persongroup.
But on reading the personGroup after that, the personGroup contains not the new membership.
After redeploying or something similar, the persongroup has the new membership. The persist process is successful. Only something in JPA cache is going wrong.

With

```
Membership membership = new Membership();
membership.setPerson(person);
membership.setPersonGroup(personGroup);
personGroup.getMemberships().add(membership);

membershipSession.persist(membership);
personGroupSession.merge(personGroup);
```

it works. My hope is to reduce the personGroupSession.merge(personGroup); or understanding, why I need this line.

This is my relationship mapping (reduced for the case)

```
@Entity
public class PersonGroup {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personGroup")
    private List<Membership> memberships = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Membership {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Person person;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private PersonGroup personGroup;
}


@Entity
public class Person {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Membership> memberships = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that multiple cached instances exist

Comment: Please share your relationship mapping - this might be the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In following code snipet

```
Membership membership = new Membership();
membership.setPerson(person);
membership.setPersonGroup(personGroup);
personGroup.getMemberships().add(membership);

membershipSession.persist(membership);
```

what you are doing is simply creating a Membership and persisting it you are assigning it to the PersonGroup but then changed state of person group is not merged with database. while in case of the second snipet

```
Membership membership = new Membership();
membership.setPerson(person);
membership.setPersonGroup(personGroup);
personGroup.getMemberships().add(membership);

membershipSession.persist(membership);
personGroupSession.merge(personGroup);
```

You are merging the changes in the PersonGroup by calling the merge(). This is the reason why your first snipet has old personGroup while your 2nd snipet has the updated personGroup. Here is docs saying what [merge()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29) does actually.